# The AoE standard appears to have no CRC field. Is this in violation of the ethernet standard?

Tags: ethernet, ata

I've been debugging AoE in one of my setups.

In it I noticed that the AoE packets do not seem to have checksum fields on the frames.
I looked up the AoE specification and it doesn't seem to have CRC checksums on the ends of the packets defined.

Is the checksum field optional?

Answer (score 0):

Found this [AoE pdf](http://www.nas.uk.com/coraid-whitepapers/doc_download/269-aoe-overview) with frame diagrams showing the crc.
It looks like originated from Coraid.

Comment: Interesting.  I was looking at a couple of linux implementations and with wireshark and it appeared the crc was missing.  The official standard doesn't show it.

Comment: From what I know, at least from the router perspective, crc is used in layer2 to drop those corrupted frames.  If I were an AoE developer, I would get my code to handle both cases and leaning toward including crc.  (In fact, you could replay a modified frame with crc to see if your existing setup can handle it, right?)